# Solution of a special class of Diophantine Equations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Suppose A  is  Diophantine Equations which have a variable x,such that every other  variable has function of x  the variable as it's solution.For example,a Diophantine equation in three variables has two variables y,z,
$$ y = x^2+1$$
$$ z = 4x^6+2$$
as their solutions.

All Diophantine Equations like A form B, a special class of Diophantine Equations.

**EDIT**:suppose $$P_1(x,y_1,\cdots,y_n)=P_2(x,y_1,\cdots,y_n)=\cdots=P_k(x,y_1,\cdots,y_n)=0$$ is Diopantine equations ,and there are functions$$y_1=f_1(x),\cdots,y_n=f_n(x)$$,which satisify the Diopantine equations.

Question:  is any function of x for solution of other variables of such Diophantine Equations   algebraic? or are $$y_1=f_1(x),\cdots,y_n=f_n(x)$$ all algebraic?

Comment: The question really isn't well posed. The theory of diophantine equations for all curves of genus 0 (i.e. all "space curves" that are rational curves from a geometric point of view) was written down by Hilbert and Hurwitz. It is in Mordell's books. If that is not essentially the question you are asking, I'm not really understanding the question.

Comment: @François,thank you very much for your edit

Comment: @Charles,I think there must be some misunderstanding,I think I am not asking about question of curves of genus 0.maybe some of them are about curves of genus 0.The example is just a very special case.

Comment: If each variable can be written as a *rational function* of x, then the curve has genus zero. If not, then what does "every other variable has function of x the variable as it's solution" mean?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you clarify?

Comment: So we have x, f(x), g(x), h(x) ... where f, g, h are certain functions. What now? Which equations are concerned? I have a feeling you want something about implicit algebraic functions.

Comment: Do you mean parametrized solutions $(x(t),y(t),z(t)$ of a Diophantine equation F(x,y,z)=0$ ? 

Comment: @quim,@François,@Charles,@ Dietrich ,we just suppose other variables can have a function of x  ,and the functions satisify the Diophantine equations,I do not know what functions they are,some of them may be rational  ,lik the example,some of them may be algebraic ,whether implicit or explicit,is it possible that some of them transcendental?.Dietrich,I am not asking about parametrization of solution,I know parametrized solutions may be transcendental,like modular function.

Comment: @all,and such Diophantine equations may be a system of equation,and we suppose we just ask about other variables' solutions which is a function of one variable in the equations or equation,there are two variables in Diophantine equations or more,three variables is also just a special case .it is irrelevent whether such Diophantine equations have integer as solution or not.

Comment: I don't see why you should expect automorphic functions to parametrize arbitrary varieties.  If you have a smooth plane curve $P(x,y)=0$ of positive genus, you cannot write $y$ as a function of $x$ without choosing branches.  A standard example is $y^2 = x^3+1$, where $y=\pm \sqrt{x^3+1}$ is not really a function of $x$, and is not automorphic (as far as I know).

Comment: @S. Carnahan,http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Algebraic_function Have I misunderstood what parametrization of algebraic function is ?Or the function like
$$f_1(x),\cdots,f_n(x)$$
are not algebraic?

Comment: @S. Carnahan,and let me think about it carefully later

Comment: They are not all algebraic,and in some cases they are all transcendental.